# Find $A$ for linearized system $\dot{\overrightarrow{x}} = A \overrightarrow{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x'' + cx' + f(x) = 0$, with $c \geq 0$, where $f$ is a smooth enough function.

We can write this as a two-dimensional system:

$x' = y$
$y' = -cx' -f(x)$

The critical points of this system are given by $(z,0)$, where $z$ is a solution of $f(z) = 0$.

In general we can write $\dot{\overrightarrow{x}} = A \overrightarrow{x}$, where $A$ is the Jacobian matrix, for a linearized system.
Now I am looking for the  2×2 matrix $A$ that belongs to the critical point $(z,0)$ of the two-dimensional system above.

If we substitute  $(z,0)$ in the system we'll get $x' = 0$ and $y'= -c \cdot 0 - f(z) = 0$. But this would give a zero matrix for $A$. I have the feeling that this is not what we want. Is something wrong?

Comment: By choice a fixed point is a point that satisfies $\dot{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x}}=0$... Also plugging $(z,0)$ into the system gives $y'=cz-f(z)$

Comment: There was a typo. The expression for $y'$ should be $y' = -cx' -f(x)$ instead of $y' = -cx -f(x)$.

Comment: You need to rewrite the system as $x' = y, \quad y' = -cy - f(x)$. Then the linearization at $(z,0)$ uses the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -f'(z) & -c \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is found by differentiating the two RHS with respect to $x$ and $y$. Let $g_1(x,y) = y$ and $g_2(x,y) = -cy-f(x)$. Then

$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial g_1(x,y)}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g_1(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial g_2(x,y)}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g_2(x,y)}{\partial y}
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-f'(x) & -c
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Then you can plug the values for $x,y$ in the expression for $A$ to find out the particular linearization at the particular point.